# Control a Sony EVI-D90 PTZ (visca protocol) by using a joystick who is not support visca but only Pelco

Tags: protocols, digital-cameras

That's nice to have such community to look for help when we need.
I have a Sony EVI-D90 camera which support VISCA protocol, and I have a joystick controller from HIKVISION DS1003KI which supports quite a few protocol but not VISCA.
My question is can I use this joystick and maybe the Pelco-D protocol to control my Sony EVI-D90 PTZ Camera?

Comment: you did not say if the joystick controller, or the camera, supports the Pelco-D protocol

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Of course the joystick support the Pelco-D protocol. But the Sony Evi-D90 I'm not sure. Because there is no setting in the camera to change the protocol.

Comment: then why don't you connect the two devices and run a test? ... refer to the camera datasheet for info about supported protocols